# Xpages Get List of Online User from Domino Admin

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

in XPages i would like to get online user who logged from http(web based). I can see it from Domino Admin Panel but What i want to do is to get all logged users. is it possible? See my screen below. There are no unread documents left but I could not find any clue. If it's possible I just would like to know where to start digging or is there any other way to make it done.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Java to send the `show inetusers` command and then parse the result.

Here's a working example that you can use to send console commands and show the result:

```
<xp:table styleClass="sherlockFormTable" id="console">
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="Server console commands" />
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td colspan="2">
            <xp:inputText id="consoleCommand" value="#{viewScope.consoleCommand}" style="font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;font-size: 11px;" />
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:button value="Send command to server" id="button1">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="console" execMode="partial" execId="console">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                        viewScope.consoleResult = sessionAsSigner.sendConsoleCommand("", viewScope.consoleCommand);
                        viewScope.consoleResult = viewScope.consoleResult.replace("\n", "<br />");      
                    }]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td colspan="4">
            <xp:text id="consoleResult" value="#{viewScope.consoleResult}" style="font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;font-size: 11px;" escape="false" />
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
```